# Apache2 H10292 Invalid proxy UDS filename error after automatic update (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, apache2.4

This morning Apache2 was automaticaly updated on my Ubuntu 20.04 server:

```
Start-Date: 2021-09-28  06:37:07
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: apache2-data:arm64 (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.3, 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.5), apache2-bin:arm64 (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.3, 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.5), apache2:arm64 (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.3, 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.5), apache2-utils:arm64 (2.4.41-    4ubuntu3.3, 2.4.41-4ubuntu3.5)
End-Date: 2021-09-28  06:37:20
```

All my websites are down along with a 500 error since then.
Here's what I've found out in the apache error log:

```
[Tue Sep 28 08:40:34.983062 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 1806:tid 281473819050384] [client 192.168.1.17:51286] AH10292: Invalid proxy UDS filename (proxy:unix:///var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sites.mydomain.com.sock|fcgi://sites//srv/www/sites/html/bookend/index.php)
```

Should I reconfigure the PHP settings ?
Should I upgrade/downgrade apache ?
What can I do ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As explained in this [post](https://talk.plesk.com/threads/all-domains-apache2-error-500.362208/page-3) I've installed the 2.4.49 apache version through a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2  
sudo apt install apache2
```

Everything is back to normal now.
It's also a good idea to prevent any future automatic apache updates to avoid version conflicts:

```
sudo apt-mark hold apache2
```

Answer (score -1):

It happened a lot today apparently. There's a workaround for this that you can apply manually though:

1. Log through SSh.
2. Then download this `wget https://plesk.zendesk.com/hc/article_attachments/4407408199954/PPPM-13232.tgz && tar -xvf PPPM-13232.tgz -C /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/Template/Variable/Domain/`
3. Rebuild config: `plesk sbin httpdmng --reconfigure-all`

Hopefully that will do. More info [here](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407366133906-Website-suddenly-started-to-show-500-error-AH10292-Invalid-proxy-UDS-filename).

Answer (score -1):

I found this information on the plesk page: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4407366133906-Website-on-Plesk-server-suddenly-started-to-show-500-error-AH10292-Invalid-proxy-UDS-filename

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).